# Honeypot confused where to deploy

Tags: honeypot

Planning to deploy honeypot dionaea. Where should I deploy it?

- Google cloud (free trial)
- Raspberry pi (internal network)

My home network is: `router------ddwrt------raspberry pi (honeypot)`

And on the same router ddwrt my desktop is also connected and router acts an access point.

Please tell me rules where I can block out traffic of raspberry pi in my LAN.

Comment: I think that if you need help segregating your honeypot from the rest of your network that setting up a honeypot in a safe manner is probably beyond your skillset at this time. I would advise against doing this, especially on a home network, until you have a firm grasp of the security concepts required to do so safely.

Comment: Short answer is: do not deploy a honeypot in your own home unless you are a networking expert. If you can get free space in the cloud, do that.

Comment: What if i create a vlan and put honeypot in another vlan and natt that vlan with iptables in my raspberry pi or install a virtual router or firewall and route the traffic through it